# Div's stacking on each other?

Tags: html, css

I made a code that creates 3 divs, with images and hyperlinks inside them. However, each div should have a padding-right of 200px, and this can't be done in CSS, because I tried and it didn't work, strangely. So these 3 divs are stacking on eachother, whereas they should have 200px of space apart each other. Please help

Code:

```
<?php
    define('RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2',3);
    define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2', '<div id="rand%s" style="width:170px;height:1px; float:left;text-align:center;top"><img src="%s" style="border-style:solid;border-width:2px;border-color:black;"/><a href="%s" alt="%s" title2="%s">%s</a></div>');


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$images = array (
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic2.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello' ),
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic7.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ),
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic9.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ), 
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic5.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ),     
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic3.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello3' )
);

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if ( count($images) < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2 ) {
    trigger_error('Not enough images given', E_USER_WARNING);
    exit;
}

 #------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for ($i = 0; $i < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2; $i++) {
    shuffle($images);

    $tmp = array_shift($images);
    printf( RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2,$i, $tmp['src2'], $tmp['href2'], $tmp['title2'],     $tmp['title2'],$tmp['text2'] );    }
?>
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to see the markup output of this code.

Comment: Your style="...float:left" on the <div> is what is causing them to do that.

Comment: Skip the PHP. It's utterly useless, since you're asking about html/css.

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-right:200px;` in your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I think a viable solution would be to add `padding-right: 200px;` to your style block inside `define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2'`.

Comment: Using padding-right would be a poor choice only in that padding actually inflates the container size. If a div of width 50 is given a padding-right of 200px, the container is now of size 250 which could cause other layout flaws.

Instead, use margin-right: 200px to cause a gap between nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
 define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2', '<div id="rand%s" style="width:170px;height:1px; float:left;text-align:center;top"><img src="%s" style="border-style:solid;border-width:2px;border-color:black;"/><a href="%s" alt="%s" title2="%s">%s</a></div>');
```

I would REALLY use CSS styles instead of inline styles on the DIV tag...but that aside, the float:left property is causing your  containers to have a position:absolute value and pull to the same left position. Instead, remove the float:left, remove the margin on the DIV container and then use a margin-right:50px or whatever distance apart you want them to be to space them.